# Displaying array inside object from mongodb in pug

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have an object which contains an object of arrays which name is provided by the product ordered. I cannot get into displaying this array simply by doing something like `order.product1` in pug. 
I need to display any name and the whole request body in some nice way.

First cut of code is code i use in jade to display basic infos. 
Order.details is displaying me literally everything but in the way that mongodb sends it to me. Like `{name:["1","35"]...}` etc.

```
each order, i in Orders
     tr.table-success
     form(method="POST" action="/reservations/send-confirmation" id="form1")
      td
       input(value=order.created)
      td 
       input(value=order.clientName)
      td
       input(value=order.clientNip)
      td 
       input(value=order.companyProfit)
      td 
       input(value=order.orderValue)
      td 
      input(value=order.details)
```

I'm keep getting nothing and it'd be cool just to show some certain arrays in object.

Comment: You'll have to share the structure of the Orders object or some sample data to better understand this problem.

Comment: [link](https://imgur.com/f5NUB2R) 
Here it is and i need to display the whole object